# is there a difference in outcome between fast-forward-merge-commit and a cherry-pick from a side branch?

Tags: git

I would like to have a clean git history without any merge commits.
The git is being used by a team.
two different strategies I thought of:

1. After a developer has finished working on their side-branch, they squash all of their commits, they rebase against `dev` and resolve all conflicts, and then they cherry-pick their side-branch into `dev` and push.
2. After a developer has finished working on their side-branch, they squash all of their commits, they rebase against `dev` and resolve all conflicts, and then they merge into `dev` using `fast-forward-merge-commit`.

Would there be any difference in the outcome git history on `dev` ?  if yes, why ?

Answer (score -1):

Addressing just the title question itself: yes, there is a huge difference:

- Cherry-pick works by *copying* a commit.  The new-and-improved copy has a different hash ID, and you now have two commits that "do the same thing" but have different hash IDs.
- A fast-forward operation moves a branch name to a commit hash ID.  No commits change; no new commits appear; one branch name that used to name some old commit, now names some newer commit.  For this operation to be a fast-forward, the old commit (the one the name selected before) must be an ancestor of the new commit (the one the name selects now).

Your two sub-questions are quite different, though, as they involve running various commands in one repository, then running `git push` to deliver commits *from* that one repository, *to* a second repository, followed by asking the second repository to move a branch name.

> Would there be any difference in the outcome git history on `dev`?

Let me start with three points.  We'll need these to make sense of the real answers you need here.

#### History = commits

Git's history is nothing more or less than the commits in the repository, as found by some name(s).  The `git log` command works by:

- finding a commit, or multiple commits, as specified on the command line: the default is the `HEAD` commit;
- putting this commit's hash ID into a queue (specifically a priority queue, but this only matters when there are multiple commits in the queue);

then looping:

- take the next commit *out* of the queue;
- print it, or suppress the printing in some fancy cases;
- add the commit's parent or parents to the queue, or don't in some fancy cases;
- repeating this loop until the queue is empty.

This depends on the parent(s) of each commit to *find* the history, and is how and why Git works *backwards*.  A branch name simply locates the *last* commit in some chain of commits.  As long as there are no actual merge commits in the chain, and you kick the process off with a single commit, the queue only ever has one commit in it—or zero commits, temporarily, while processing each commit and upon reaching the very first commit ever (which by definition has no parent).

#### Branch names (and other names) find commits; these names are *not shared*

The branch names in some repository serve to find commit hash IDs.  Each branch name stores one single hash ID.  For instance, `dev` might mean commit `a123456...`.  (The actual hash IDs are big and ugly and nobody can remember them, which is why we have branch names to remember them for us.)

Each *repository* has *its own private names*.  When you hook two repositories to each other, they get to *see* each the other's names (to some extent), but they're not required to use the *same* names.  What's shared are the *commits themselves*.  Commits have *universal hash IDs:* commit `a123456...` has that hash ID in *every Git repository* that has the commit, and any Git repository that *doesn't* have the commit, does not have any commit with hash ID `a123456...`.

Two Gits, in other words, decide if they both have commit `a123456...` by checking the *ID*, not the name.  This is important since they may not use the same *name* for that hash ID.  One Git might have six names for that ID, and other Git have only one name.  Or, repository R1 might have names `fred` and `barney`, and repository R2 have `wilma` and `betty` instead.  But if they both have commit `a123456...`, they both use the same hash ID for *that particular commit*.

In a sense, the hash ID *is* the commit (except that it's a lot shorter).  The hash ID *represents* the commit, and if your Git doesn't have the hash ID, it doesn't have the commit either; if it does have the hash ID, it has the commit.

#### Commits store commit hash IDs

To make the whole backwards-chain thing work in the first place, each commit stores the *raw hash ID* of its predecessor.  There are no names involved here, just raw hash IDs:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This represents a chain of commits (probably 8 commits, given the letters that come before `F` :-) ) in a row, where we've replaced the actual random-looking hash IDs with single uppercase letters.  The *last* commit in this chain has hash ID `H`.  It consists of a snapshot of all files, plus some metadata, and the metadata in commit `H` contains the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

Commit `G` contains a snapshot and metadata too.  Its metadata gives the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`.  We say that `H` *points to* `G`, and `G` *points to* `F`.  `F`, of course, points to a still-earlier commit, and so on, backwards.  This is the history: some *name* allows us—or Git—to find commit `H`, and from there, Git works backwards.

#### Returning to your question

When developers do work, they're going to make *new* commits.  Exactly how they go about making new commits is not terribly important, but each new commit will have a full snapshot of every file—every commit has that; that's a fundamental part of Git; the snapshots are compressed and de-duplicated so that we don't have to worry about using up the disk drive—and some metadata.  The metadata will have their name as author and committer, a date-and-time-stamp, a log message, and so on; and the metadata of each *new* commit will automatically point back to some *older* commit.

In other words, they might start out with:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev
```

They could then create a new, arbitrary branch name X, or just use the name `dev`.  It doesn't really matter that much *now*, because they'll have another name, a *non-branch* name, `origin/dev`, that finds commit `H` for now.  It could matter later, because as soon as they run `git fetch` to get any *new* commits from `origin`, that might give them a new commit on `origin`'s `dev`, and their Git will then update their own `origin/dev`.

So, let's say they create a branch named `X` and use `git checkout` or `git switch` to make it their *current branch*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, origin/dev, X (HEAD)
```

The `HEAD` notation here shows which *branch name* is the *current branch*.  It's actually the branch name that selects the commit, so that commit `H` is the current *commit*.  Regardless of which of these names they use to find `H`, they will find `H` right now.

Now they make a new commit (in the usual way).  This new commit gets a new, unique (across *every* Git repository) hash ID: maybe `b789abc...` but we'll just call it commit `I`.  Their Git writes this commit into their repository database.  It makes `I` have `H` as parent, because `H` is the *current commit* at the moment:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

The name `dev` does not update, because that's not their *current branch*.  So it still points to `H`.  The name `origin/dev` does not update—only `git fetch` updates it, and only if the *other* Git repository has changed *its* `dev` branch: `origin/dev` is our developer's Git's repository's method of remembering some other Git's `dev`.  But the name `X`, which is the *current branch*, *does* change: Git writes `I`'s hash ID into this name, so that it continues to point to the newest commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, origin/dev
         \
          I   <-- X (HEAD)
```

If our developer makes another new commit `J`, this commit will point back to existing commit `I`, and now `X` points to `J`:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, origin/dev
         \
          I--J   <-- X (HEAD)
```

Assuming that commit `J` finishes off the work, it's now time for our developer to put his new commit(s) into action.  But meanwhile, over on the `origin` Git, someone else has added new commits.  Our developer should run `git fetch` now.  (Note that `git fetch` is the first part of `git pull`, but I'm going to suggest that our developer *not bother with `git pull` at all* here.)

Let's draw a picture of the corporate repository, which used to go like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev
```

It now has some new commits.  We need letter other than `I` or `J`; let's jump to `P` and assume there's just one commit:

```
...--G--H--P   <-- dev
```

Note that this repository's `dev` now points to commit `P`.

Our developer runs `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`.  (The latter just says where to go for the fetch; if there's only one other repository to call up for fetching, there's no need to say that.)  The two Gits hook up, and, since the direction-of-transfer is "from corporate to worker-bee", the only *new* commit is commit `P`.  Our developer gets commit `P` in his repository, and his Git updates his `origin/dev` to point to it:

```
          P   <-- origin/dev
         /
...--G--H   <-- dev
         \
          I--J   <-- X (HEAD)
```

Our developer doesn't actually *need* the name `dev` at all.  I recommend that he just delete it, which lets us draw this more simply:

```
...--G--H--P   <-- origin/dev
         \
          I--J   <-- X (HEAD)
```

This is the same drawing; we just took one *name* away.  Our developer doesn't really need to find commit `H` directly via the name `dev`.  (He can, if he wants to, keep the name so that he can find where he started from, but `origin/dev` will actually work fine here.)

Our developer now needs to make a new commit that *follows commit `P`*.  We'll call this commit `K`, which we made room for.  No part of any *existing* commit can ever be changed!  The content for new commit `K` should be:

- metadata: author, committer, log message, etc., as dictated by the developer;
- metadata: parent: `P`
- snapshot: the result of merging `J` and `P`

There are *lots of ways for our developer to get new commit `K` made*.  He can:

- use `git rebase -i` or similar to squash together `I` and `J` into a new `IJ` that follows `H`, then use `git rebase` to copy `IJ` to a new `K` that follows `P`;
- use `git rebase` to copy `I` and `J` to new commits `I'` and `J'` that follow `P`, then squash `I` and `J` together to make `K`;
- use `git merge --squash` to make `K` directly (this might be my personal choice);

or anything else the developer likes.  It doesn't matter *how* our developer gets there.  What matters is that he makes commit `K`:

```
             K   <--  new-name (HEAD)
            /
...--G--H--P   <-- origin/dev
         \
          I--J   <-- X
```

This is a picture of the result of creating a new branch name, checking it out, and running `git merge --squash X`, with:

```
git switch -c new-name origin/dev
git merge --squash X
```

But:

```
git rebase origin/dev
```

would do this:

```
             I'-J'  <-- X (HEAD)
            /
...--G--H--P   <-- origin/dev
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

after which `git rebase -i origin/dev` and turning `pick` into `squash` would do this:

```
               I'-J'  [abandoned]
              /
             /--K   <-- X (HEAD)
            /
...--G--H--P   <-- origin/dev
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

No matter how they go about this, as long as they end up with the desired result—a commit, or several commits, that simply *add on* to commit `P`—they can now *send* the new commits:

```
git push origin new-branch:dev
```

would be the way to do this with the drawing I made of my *make new branch then use `git merge --squash`* method, and:

```
git push origin X:dev
```

would be the way to do this with the drawing just above.  Either way, the developer has his Git call up the corporate Git and send new commits found by name—`new-name` or `X`—that aren't in the corporate Git.  Any old `I-J` commits aren't found by any of these names: they're all abandoned or irrelevant.  So only commit `K` goes over.  Then the developer Git asks (politely) that the corporate Git update *their* `dev` name, so that *their* `dev` would point to commit `K`.

#### It's this `git push` that results in a proper fast-forward

This `git push`—run *without* `--force`—sends some commit(s) to the corporate Git server, then sends the polite request: *Please, if it's OK, set your name `dev` to point to this last new commit.*  The corporate Git server checks to make sure that the new commits *add on* to the currently-last-commit for that branch name.

If the new commits *do* just add-on, the corporate Git treats the request as a fast-forward, and does it; it replies: *OK, I did that;* and the developer's Git updates their `origin/dev` because they see that the polite request was granted.

If, by whatever coincidences occurred, commit `K` *doesn't* add on to the corporate chain—for instance, if commit `P` got added-on-to by developer13 so that the corporate Git chain now ends at commit `Q`:

```
...--H--P--Q   <-- dev
         \
          K   [request]
```

then the corporate Git says *No, I can't do that because it would drop some commit(s)*.  They don't get specific about commit `Q` here, they just say *no, it's not a fast-forward*.  The developer's Git then prints a complaint for the developer to see: `rejected (non-fast-forward)` and *does not* update his `origin/dev`.  He must run `git fetch` to obtain commit `Q` *from* the corporate Git now, and come up with a new commit—let's call it `L` or `K'`—that adds on to `Q`.

Now, some of your developers might be uncomfortable with the idea that *their* branch names don't match your corporate branch names.  If that's the case, you can let them keep their local `dev` branch names, and spend a bunch of time and effort updating their `dev` to match their `origin/dev` after using `git fetch` to update their `origin/dev`.  But this really isn't terribly useful.  It's a whole bunch of unnecessary running-around.  If they learn how to operate Git directly, they can avoid all of this.

#### If you go through GitHub or other web hosting sites

The big drawback to letting developers push directly like this is a lack of control: you have to *trust* your developers (not to use `git push --force`, for instance).  If you go through the fancy hosting sites, that have controls like protected branches and forks and so on, you can prevent developers from breaking stuff.  This does, however, put more of a burden on you—or some trusted developers—to manage the merges into the main repository.  Only you can decide whether this sort of thing is worthwhile.

If you want to do this on your own corporate servers, there are systems like Gitolite that let you stuff similar to what GitHub does, without having to involve GitHub or Bitbucket or GitLab.  Gitolite does not have a fancy issue tracker and code review system, though, so the web hosting sites may have other features you'd like.